# Manipulating the derivative of (-1)^(x/a)+(-1)^(x/(a+5)) with respect to the parameter a

Tags: plotting, manipulate, calculus-and-analysis

I'd just like to know if it is possible to use `Manipulate` for to show how the derivative of an expression such as

```
(-1)^(x/a)+(-1)^(x/(a+5))
```

varies with respect to the parameter `a`.

In Mathematica I can't just write derivative(equation) and get a result as I can do on-line with Wolfram|Alpha. In Mathematica I write

```
f[x_] := (-1)^(x/a) + (-1)^(x/(a + 7))
```

on one line and write

```
Manipulate[Plot[{Re{f'[x]]}, {x, 0, 10}, {a, 1, 10}]
```

on another. You guys probably know I get a plot, but I can't vary `a`, because I didn't write the whole thing within `Manipulate`.

How can I write this correctly?

Comment: `f[x_, a_] := (-1)^(x/a) + (-1)^(x/(a + 7)); Manipulate[Plot[Evaluate@Re@D[f[x, a], x], {x, 0, 10}], {a, 1, 10}]`

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!